# What does "${-#*i}" != "$-" mean?

Tags: shell, shell-script

In `/etc/profile` I see this:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
        fi
    fi
done
```

What does `${-#*i}` mean. I cannot find a definition of a parameter expansion starting `${-`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`$-` is current option flags set by the shell itself, on invocation, or using the `set` builtin command:

```
$ echo $-
himBH
$ set -a
$ echo $-
ahimBH
```

`"${-#*i}"` is syntax for string removal: (from [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02))

> ${parameter#[word]}
>
> Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce
>   a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter,
>   with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern
>   deleted. If present, word shall not begin with an unquoted '#'.
>
> ${parameter##[word]}
>
> Remove Largest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a
>   pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with
>   the largest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.

So `${-#*i}` remove the shortest string till the first `i` character:

```
$ echo "${-#*i}"
mBH
```

In your case, `if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]` checking if your shell is interactive or not.

Answer (score 25):

There is a shell parameter `$-`. In my case:

```
$ echo $-
himB
```

`${-}` is the same as `$-` exactly like `${foo}` is the same as `$foo`.

`#*i` means: Delete (as little as possible; doesn't make a difference here) from the beginning of the variable value until (including) the first `i`.

```
$ echo "${-#*i}"
mB
```

In other words: `[ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]` checks whether there is an `i` in the value of the `$-` variable, that is, it checks if the shell is interactive.

In other words, it's a convoluted and non-Bourne compatible way to write:

```
case $- in
  *i*) ...;;
  *) ...;;
esac
```

Comment: It _is_ [POSIX-compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), though.